# How to "continue" in a loop in smalltalk

Tags: loops, smalltalk, continue

I have following code where I want to 'continue' if i is less than 5:

```
1 to: 10 do: [ :i |
    i < 5 ifTrue: [ continue ].
    'Square of i = ', (i * i) printNl.
]
```

'continue' in above code is obviously not working. I know that `exit` can be used to break out of a loop. But how to `continue`? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can simply use `ifFalse:`:

```
1 to: 10 do: [ :i |
    i < 5 ifTrue: [ 
        "Any code you need"
    ] ifFalse: [ 'Square of i = ', (i * i) printNl ].
]
```

The following code will probably work only in Pharo. (it will not work in GNU Smalltalk, in Smalltalk/X it could work if you use correct modulo.  The `%` returns complex number):

```
    1 to: 10 do: [ :i |
        [ :continue |
            i % 5 = 0 ifTrue: [ 
                Transcript show: i; cr.
                continue value ].
            Transcript 
                show: i;
                show: ', '.     
        ] valueWithExit.
    ]
```

The `valueWithExit` the implementation in Pharo:

```
valueWithExit 
      self value: [ ^nil ]
```

The meaning:

The receiver must be block of one argument. When it is evaluated and is passed a block, when a `value` message is send will exit the receiver block (returning `nil` in Pharo).

Comment: Can you use ifTrue without ifFalse?

Comment: @rnso of course, you can even use `#ifFalse:` only.  (note that the code below it (in your example) will be always executed if you have it as you have written in your question)

Comment: There is `continue` code at: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loops/Continue#Smalltalk but I could not understand it. How can I apply that method?

Comment: If you are using GNU Smalltalk you can't as simply as in Pharo (Smalltalk/X has it implemented too but the `%` has different meaning than modulo).   It does not have the `#valueWithExit` implemented (you will get this error: `error: did not understand #valueWithExit`).  You would have to implement it yourself.  The code shown there is to show that this can be implemented but the real-life usage is limited (it can be easily implemented by using `ifTrue:ifFalse:` which is easily read, reused).  Is there any reason why you insist in the using `coninue`?

Comment: I am not insisting on use of `continue`. I saw code in rosettacode and thought it was available in all versions. Pl see this question also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086816/dead-method-context-error-in-a-function