# "Dead method context" error in a function

Tags: function, smalltalk

I am trying to write a `isBinary` function that checks sent line if it has any non-printable characters (integer value outside range 0-127):

```
isBinary := [ :sline |
    'Reached isBinary fn.' displayNl.
    sline do: [ :char |           "for each character"
        i := char asInteger.      "convert to integer"
        (i < 0 | i > 127) 
        ifTrue: [^true]. ].       "return true if found unprintable"
    ^false. ].                    "if not found above, return false"

(Directory working: '.') allFilesMatching: '*.x'
do: [ :ff |
    ((ff name), ' : ') display.
    infile := FileStream open: ff name mode: FileStream read.
        firstline := infile nextLine.
        (isBinary value: firstline) 
        ifTrue: ['Binary file' displayNl.]
        ifFalse: [ 'Not a binary file' displayNl].
    infile close ].
```

`isBinary` function is reached but, it gives following error (whether the file is binary or not):

```
$ gst isbinary.st
"Global garbage collection... done"
/home/abcd/binaryfile.x : Reached isBinary fn.
Object: Character value: 16rC0 error: return from a dead method context
SystemExceptions.BadReturn(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
SystemExceptions.BadReturn class(Exception class)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:151)
Character(Object)>>badReturnError (Object.st:1389)
String(SequenceableCollection)>>do: (SeqCollect.st:827)
[] in UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (isbinary.st:4)
optimized [] in UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (isbinary.st:16)
[] in Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper(FilePath)>>filesMatching:do: (FilePath.st:903)
[] in Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper>>namesDo:prefixLength: (VFS.st:378)
[] in File>>namesDo: (File.st:589)
BlockClosure>>ensure: (BlkClosure.st:268)
File>>namesDo: (File.st:586)
Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper>>namesDo:prefixLength: (VFS.st:373)
[] in Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper>>namesDo:prefixLength: (VFS.st:382)
[] in File>>namesDo: (File.st:589)
BlockClosure>>ensure: (BlkClosure.st:268)
File>>namesDo: (File.st:586)
Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper>>namesDo:prefixLength: (VFS.st:373)
Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper>>namesDo: (VFS.st:396)
Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper(FilePath)>>filesMatching:do: (FilePath.st:902)
File(FilePath)>>allFilesMatching:do: (FilePath.st:775)
Directory class>>allFilesMatching:do: (Directory.st:225)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (isbinary.st:11)
```

Replacing `sline do:` with `sline asArray do:` in my code also does not work (same error).

Where is the problem and how can this be solved? Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** 
As suggested in the answer and comments, I wrote following code with method in a class and this works. I just want your comments whether this is the right method.

```
Object subclass: Checker [ 
    isBinary: sline [ 
        'Reached isBinary fn.' displayNl.
        sline do: [ :char |  | i |           "for each character"
            i := char asInteger.             "convert to integer"
            i > 127
            ifTrue: [^true]     "return true if found unprintable"  
        ].       
    ^false. ]      "if no unprintable char found, return false"
].

(Directory working: '.') allFilesMatching: '*.x'
do: [ :ff |
    '------------------------------' displayNl.
    ((ff name), ' : ') displayNl.
    infile := FileStream open: ff name mode: FileStream read.
        firstline := infile nextLine.
        ((Checker new) isBinary: firstline)
        ifTrue: ['Binary file' displayNl.]
        ifFalse: [ 'Not a binary file' displayNl].
    infile close ].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `isBinary` variable is bound to a block that contains a so called *non-local return*, which cannot be executed the way you intend. The reason is that the semantics for a non-local return is to return from the method that defines de block (it's lexical context). If such a method does not exist or it already returned (in other words if the lexical context is not in the calling stack), there is no way to define where the execution flow should return. Hence the error.

To solve this, just create a method `#isBinary:` that receives an argument `sline` with the code you wrote for the block. Then call the method instead of evaluating the block. That will work.

Comment: How do I create #isBinary? Just rename my function to this name? Or do I need to create a separate class with this method? I wanted to avoid creating a new class. Your code example will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can write `sline allSatisfy: [:char | char asInteger > 127]` and avoid the problem because you will have a clean block not referring to outer context

Comment: @aka.nice Actually `anySatisfy` works well: `sline anySatisfy: [:char | char asInteger > 127]`. Thanks.

Comment: @rnso This answer is indeed about the same as mine to your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56100970/383568). The added difficulty here is that you want to "break" from the loop of your `isBinary`. Without a proper method to return from, this is not easily possible. `anySatisfy` is a proper method and it will return from its loop with such a non-local return just like in your original code.

Comment: @rnso  Leandro recommends that you create a proper method for `isBinary` (then with an argument, hence the added colon). I agree with him and, since you only seem to have run simple scripts from the command line so far, recommend that you learn how to create classes and methods in GNU Smalltalk instead of just running simple scripts, which are essentially a single method. If you already know how to do it, you should not avoid it for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Can you please add here an answer showing how to "create a proper method for isBinary". I do not fully understand what is meant by this phrase. And that is why I am not able to accept answer available here.

Comment: I don't normally use GNU Smalltalk, so I would have to look that up myself. @LeandroCaniglia, @aka.nice Do you know the proper syntax for GNU Smalltalk to create a class with the `isBinary:` method and the matching gst invocation?

Comment: @rnso As I wrote above, I would have to do the same work now that lies ahead of you: look up in the GNU Smalltalk documentation how to write files that contain classes and how to load them into the system. GNU Smalltalk is an "odd" Smalltalk because it does not have an IDE (even though Smalltalk very much invented that concept), but wants you to write the code in files instead. That's why I cannot single-handedly answer your request although it may seem to you like an everyday operation. :-)

Comment: So basically, I have to create a class with isBinary method. Then it should work.

Comment: Exactly. This is how Smalltalk was conceived: (1) identify new objects, (2) create classes for modeling them, (3) define the behavior of objects as methods and (4) go to (1)

Answer (score 0):

Following standalone method/block code works by creating a return variable whose value is manipulated in loop if unprintable character is found. The loop is then exited:

```
isBinary := [ :sline |            "WORKS"
    'Reached isBinary fn: ' display.
    ret := false.                 "return variable initialized to false"
    sline do: [ :char |           "loop for each character in sent line"
        i := char asInteger.      "convert to integer"
        i > 127                   "check if printable"
        ifTrue: [ret := true. exit]].   "ret becomes true if found unprintable; does not work if ^ symbol is used"  
    ret].            "if not found above, ret remains false; ret is returned value"
```

Above works without creating a class as desired by OP (me!).