# Why this method's return part is not working

Tags: function, methods, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I am trying to write a method which returns a new value. Following code is modified from [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_a_set_of_characters_from_a_string#Smalltalk):

```
| stripChars |
stripChars := [ :string :chars |    
    str := string reject: [ :c | chars includes: c ].
    str displayNl.          "THIS WORKS."
    ^ str                   "THIS DOES NOT WORK."
].

newstr := stripChars 
    value: 'She was a soul stripper. She took my heart!'
    value: 'aei'.
newstr displayNl.
```

Although above function creates new string and displays it, there is error in returning or receiving returned new string:

```
$ gst make_fn_ques.st
Sh ws  soul strppr. Sh took my hrt!
Object: 'Sh ws  soul strppr. Sh took my hrt!' error: return from a dead method context
SystemExceptions.BadReturn(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
SystemExceptions.BadReturn class(Exception class)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:151)
String(Object)>>badReturnError (Object.st:1389)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (make_fn_ques.st:10)
nil
```

Where is the problem and how can this be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that your stripChars is neither a function nor a method. It is called a block. It is a callable closure and belongs to the enclosing method context (similar to a stack frame).

Comment: You can do simply `string reject: [ :c | chars includes: c ]` without variable assignment.

Comment: Remark: From your recent questions I get the impression that you are trying to learn smalltalk. GST is not really the most suitable platform for that, its strengths are elsewhere. Your learning experience might be better using one of the image and GUI based Smalltalks, like Pharo, Squeak or Cuis.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did not know about `Cuis`. What are major strengths of `GST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
^ str
```

does not return from the block (stripChars), but from the enclosing method instead (non-local return).

Apparently GNU Smalltalk does not allow you to return from the script that you pass to gst in this way.

Just drop the ^, and keep only `str` as the last expression of the block. That will cause `str` to be the return value of the block.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I had a similar question earlier for which I could not get an acceptable answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086816/dead-method-context-error-in-a-function/56086952#56086952

Comment: No Smalltalk dialect allows non-local returns from scripted blocks because of their semantics. A non-local return should take the execution flow to the sender of the method that defined the block, which is impossible if the block has been scripted and saved in a variable. Since the execution flow has no place to go, the system signals an error (there is no other option).